# Disable drag and drop of columns in jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using JQuery Datatables Plugin ([datatable](http://www.datatables.net/examples/index)). I want to disable reordering of columns,

Below is my code.

```
.DataTable({
            "serverSide" : true,
             "bFilter": false, 
             "bInfo": false,
             responsive: true,

             sDom: "Rlfrtip",
            "pagingType" : "simple_numbers",
            "pageLength" : 10,
            "bLengthChange" : false,
            "drawCallback":enableTimer(trainingTableRefreshFrequency),
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : getAllTraniningServiceUrl,
                "data" : function(d) {
                     d.searchKey=$("#searchKey").val();

                     d.searchValue=$("#searchValue").val();

                },
                type : 'POST'
            },
             "language": {
                    "emptyTable":     "No Data Available"
                },
            "columns" : [ {
                "orderable" : false,
                "searchable" : false,

                "data" : null,



            ]


        });
```

What are the ways to disable reordering of columns.

Comment: What is the result you are getting with your code? The columns params has invalid code. You have a comma and no closing `}`. Is something missing from here? https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable